# How to do something only after all the scheduled tasks are finished?

Tags: java, timer, schedule, timertask

Im pretty new in java, and there is a problem that i need to face it. If i do this:

```
//somecode
double number=0;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new someFunction(),0,1);
```

How can i do something else, only after this schedule is finished(it will, after some interactions)?

If i try this:

```
//somecode
double number=0;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new someFunction(),0,1);
number=1;
```

The change in number will happen before the task end. Is there a way to solve this? I wrote a functional code to expose better my question:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Main {


    public static void main( String[ ] args ) {

        class SomeTask extends TimerTask {

            private double someVariable;
            public SomeTask(double someVariable){
                this.someVariable=someVariable;

            }


            public void run() {

                while(this.someVariable<10){
                    this.someVariable++;
                    System.out.println(this.someVariable);
                }
                this.cancel();
            }
        }


        boolean allTaskDone=false;

        double someVariable=0;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new SomeTask(someVariable),0,1000);

        allTaskDone=true;
        System.out.println(allTaskDone);


    }
}
```

the output is :

```
true
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
10.0
```

How can i make allTaskDone be evaluated after the task is compleated? In other words, make something like this happen:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
10.0
true
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: After all the scheduled tasks? Or after every scheduled task?

Comment: A valid [mcve] would be nice to help clarify your code and your question.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, You are serializing your work. The timer is just a distraction.

Comment: answering the first question: after all the schedule tasks. Second: ok! i will work on that. Third: unfortunately no, i will need the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1 in timer.schedule(new someFunction(),0,1); means it will repeat your task every 1ms.

The following code will mimic your interactions, and do what you want. I am using a ScheduledExecutorService instead of a Timer.

```
    final FutureTask<String> task = new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() throws Exception {
            int counter = 0;
            boolean finished = false;
            while (!finished) {
                System.out.println("work in progress..." + counter);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                counter += 1;
                if (counter > 5) {
                    finished = true;
                    return "work done";
                }
            }
            return "not finished";
        }
    });

    ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    String done = task.get();
    scheduler.shutdown();
    System.out.println(done);
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what i wanted!

Comment: Laurent, your solution does what i asked, but there is a way to do this using Time class? I need to use this specifically, because only with timertask my JFreechart lineChart can change dynamically.

Comment: your allTaskDone has to be updated by the tasks themselves. Either refer to a Map of key task UUID unique identifier, boolean value taskIsDone, and only fire allTaskDone=true when there are no falses values left in the Map, or better, use a BlockingQueue with Consumer (your main loop) / Producer (each task) and loop wait on queue.take() as described in http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example